# How to extract numbers with delimiter from a string?

Tags: python, string, python-3.x, delimiter

I am trying to extract the numbers with delimiters from a filename (for version check purpose). I have the filename as `filename= bacserv.v1.2.6` and `not with quotes ('')`. I am using RegEx as below but RegEx takes the input as `'bacserv.v1.2.6'` with quotes. My expected output is `1.2.6` or `"1.2.6"`. Can anyone help?

```
import re
matches = re.findall('\d+', 'bacserv.v1.2.6')
print(matches)
```

Output:

```
['1', '2', '6']
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use re.search with slightly different pattern:

```
import re
match = re.search('\d+.\d+.\d+', 'bacserv.v1.2.6')
if match:
   version = match.group()
```

Answer (score 1):

You could take your regex results one step further and apply `'.'.join(matches)`

Comment: This leads to incorrect output for inputs like `'bacserv.v1.2.61'` -> `'1.2.6.1'`

Comment: truth be told , taking it down

Comment: @PatrickHaugh would `'.'.join()` not work on his current approach?

Comment: @PatrickHaugh his regex should match properly for that case you provided, correct?

Comment: That would be better.  There are still some (less likely) scenarios where that would produce strange output though: `'bac123serv.v1.2.6'` -> `123.1.2.6`, which may not be intended

Comment: @patrickhaugh okay well I’ll leave as is and let Op chime in but I’m known for my endless questioning of what ifs, I should have known better on my first response, ty appreciate it

Comment: @hossain awesome! Cheers :)

Answer (score 1):

How about the following? Assuming the version number always follows ".v" in the filename:

```
import re
m = re.search('(\.v)([\d\.]+)', 'bacserv.v1.2.6')
print(m.group(2))
```